# How to search a range to see if the range is missing a row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a set of data that contains statistics for every hour in a month.

Sometimes, the data is missing a line (for example, when the database is down for maintenance, so we are not able to collect statistics).  What I need to do is determine if in each 24 hour block if hour column increases by 1 each time.  If the value in the hour column increases by 2, I need to add a blank row, and populate each of the cells with a 0.

This is what I have tried to do:

```
Sub btnAddZero()
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim intOffset As Integer

    'select the starting row for counting the hours
    Set srcRange = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A4")
    'Set the beginning offset to 4 to account for empty 4 rows
    intOffset = 4

    'number of days in the month
    For j = 0 To 30
        'number of hours in a day
        ' rows

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 23


                'if the first cell is not 1 more than the cell below it
                If srcRange.Cells(intOffset, 4) <> srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 4) Then
                    'shift everything below this line down
                    srcRange.Rows(intOffset + i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    'set everything in this row to be 0
                    srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 1).Value = 0
                    srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 2).Value = 0
                    'set the value to be the same value as the cell above
                    srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 3).Value = srcRange.Cells(Row - 1, 3).Value
                    srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 4).Value = 0
                    srcRange.Cells(intOffset + i, 5).Value = 0
                End If

        Next i
        intOffset = intOffset + i
        'off set the range for next 24 hours
        Set srcRange = srcRange.offset(intOffset)
    Next j

End Sub
```

Unfortunately... this sets huge ranges of rows to 0 (I believe it's inserting ~22 to 28 rows of 0's).  the first time through the outer for-loop, after the 4th iteration of the inner for-loop, this is where the row's of 0's begin.

I believe my first and biggest issue, is that my check to see if there was a missing time is not working properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a small amount of the data I am using, you can see value 15 is missing from the 4th column.  I would like to add a line of 0's after the row that contains 14.

9292    12377   2017-01-30  12  2471

11195    15028  2017-01-30  13  1392

5393    6335    2017-01-30  14  374

1911    1959    2017-01-30  16  8

11995   13181   2017-01-30  17  181

Comment: What type of value is in column 4 (presumably the timestamp)? Is it a date or time? Will it always be exactly on the hour?

Comment: It is an integer,  from 0-23 depending on the hour of the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic of how you're detecting the missing hours and inserting the rows isn't quite right. Looking a the issue a bit differently, I came up with the logic below as an example. Hopefully it's something that gets you closer to a solution.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MissingHourCheck()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Raw Data")

    Dim timeSlot As Range
    Dim nextTimeSlot As Range
    Set timeSlot = ws.Range("D5")
    Set nextTimeSlot = timeSlot.Offset(1, 0)

    Dim expectedHour As Long
    expectedHour = 0

    Do While Not IsEmpty(nextTimeSlot.Value)
        If expectedHour <> timeSlot.Value Then
            '--- oops, we're missing at least one hour.
            '    how many hours (rows) do we need to insert?
            Dim missingHours As Long
            If timeSlot.Value > expectedHour Then
                '--- it's the middle of the day, our math is easy
                missingHours = timeSlot.Value - expectedHour
            Else
                missingHours = 23 - expectedHour + 1
            End If
            timeSlot.Resize(missingHours).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            expectedHour = expectedHour + missingHours
        Else
            Set timeSlot = timeSlot.Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextTimeSlot = timeSlot.Offset(1, 0)
            expectedHour = expectedHour + 1
        End If
        If expectedHour >= 24 Then
            expectedHour = 0
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need!  Thanks again for your help!